# WCF Service - Async How to?

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

I am consuming a 'third party' WCF service. I am making to call to their method in Async mode from C# console application.

The order I am making call is
1. WCF.MethodA (Async)
2. WCF.MethodB (Async)
3. WCF.MethodC (Async)

I wanted to raise an event (which makes call to 'MethodB') after call to 'MethodA' is successfully complete. Can anyone tell me how to do that? Is that something the service needs to support (raising events)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you turn on the asynchronous option when you add the service reference, you'll get asynchronous calls with events.

For example, you should get `WCF.MethodAAsync` with a `WCF.MethodACompleted` event automatically.  You can subscribe to the completion events, and start the next method upon completion.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please point to me a sample on how to raise the event? This is the first time I am working on Async..

Comment: @CoolArchTek You don't raise the event.  Just call the `MethodAAsync` method on the client, and the event will raise when it's done.  WCF takes care of making the method asynchronous for you...

Comment: I just tried Async event.. but after WCF.MethodAAsync program exited. Do I need enable anything on the WCF Service side?

Comment: @CoolArchTek If you're doing this in a console application, you need to keep the console app from closing.  Try adding a `Console.ReadKey()` at the end of Main.  If you want something more elaborate, you could use a wait handle (ie: ManualResetEvent), and call WaitOne at the end of main.  Your handler can then call Set on the wait handle to allow it to continue (and shut down).

Comment: I was using Console.ReadKey() but don't know how to exit from application.. Can please suggest?

Comment: @CoolArchTek If you're using Console.ReadKey, it won't exit until you hit a key.  If you use ManualResetEvent, as I mentioned, it'll work.  If you need more detials, I'd actually recommend asking in a separate (detailed) question...